# How to perform a login on a remote windows system from a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, windows-embedded

I have a Windows VM and the end goal is to be able to start a Java GUI application there and be able to observe its window via RDP. To start this application, there is an SSH server on the Windows VM, which is configured to launch when the single user for that machine logs in. But right after the VM is started, this user has not logged on yet and so the SSH server is not running.

The current workaround is to perform a manual RDP login to the Windows VM, which starts the SSH server automatically, then the RDP window can even be closed, the SSH server will keep listening to the command sent to start the Java application.

I would like to either find a way to perform the login automatically instead of manually using the RDP client, OR a way to start the SSH server upon startup.

I have already tried:

1. Setting up the SSH server to run as a service - the Java application could have been started but it ran as the user SYSTEM with no visible output for us.
2. The same as 1, but running as the single configured user of the Windows VM - the application started in the name of the correct user but upon logging in as the same user via RDP the GUI of the application was not seen
3. Setting up the Windows VM to auto-login the single user, hoping that it would start the SSH service as part of the login process - same result as with 2.
4. Performing a login from a Linux VM using rdesktop - failed with "ERROR: Failed to open display", since this Linux VM does not have an X Server

If anything is not clear, I'll gladly supply additional details.